# Java proxy server keep client connection alive while switching servers

Tags: java, proxy, minecraft

I am trying to create a proxy server for minecraft that would allow the user to switch servers without relogging. What i would need to be able to do is to create a server that handles the incoming connections from the client and forward them to the appropriate server, which i have done. My question is how do you change connection to the server while still keeping the client connection alive so it dosent disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to send the player a 0x09 (respawn) packet to the client to reload the world
and send the server some packets (0x02,0x01) to log the client in
and falsify 0x0a (player update) and 0x00 (keep alive) packets to be sent to the backrounded servers

see: http://wiki.vg for more info